# Copy_to an dynamic or customised field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to configure copy_to from one dynamic template to another dynamic
template.

Here is a sample Config: -

```
"dynamic_templates": [{
"template_entity_name_": {
"match": "entity_name_*",
"match_mapping_type": "string",
"mapping": {
"type": "text",
"store": true,
"index": false,
"norms": false,
"index_options": "docs",
"copy_to": ["nameStartsWith", "wordOfNameStartsWith", "all_names",
"all_search_fields_*",
"all_search_fields", "wordOfNameStartsWith_*",
"trigrams_search_fields_*",
"whole_short_name", "whole_word" ]
}
}
}
```

if we try to index entity_name_en_US it should copy to
all_search_fields_en_US and if we try for entity_name_en_GB then it should
copy to all_search_fields_en_GB.. but its not working..

When we were working with solr we could do something like this

```
<copyField source="name_*" dest="all_search_fields_* />
```

But could not find an equivalent in Elasticsearch.

How can we solve this problem ?

Comment: Interesting. What will be replacement for this in ElasticSearch as we already have this in Solr?